# jQuery Datatable header and body width mismatch withcollapsed sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I have a datatable and a collapsible sidebar. The table has `table-layout:fixed` and I defined all of the columns width in my css. The table looks perfect when the sidbar is collapsed, but if the sidebar is opened, the column and header is misaligned. When i open firebug, I see that `dataTables_scrollHeadInner` has `width: 1558px;` but `dataTables_scrollBody` has `width:   1343px`. I have no idea why the header isn't getting resized along with the body. All codes are below (the HTML is being generated dynamically and too big to paste here):

Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    var selector = "#artist_datatable";

    var defaults = {
        "language": {
"processing": "Processing...",
"lengthMenu": "Show _MENU_ entries",
"zeroRecords": "No matching records found",
"info": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
"infoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries",
"sInfoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total entries)",
"infoPostFix": "",
"search": "Search",
"url": "",
"paginate": {
    "first": "First",
    "previous": "Previous",
    "next": "Next",
    "last": "Last"
}
}
    };

    var features = {
        "autoWidth": false,
        "deferRender": false,
         "info": true,
         "jQueryUI": false,
         "lengthChange": true,
          "ordering": true,
          "paging": true,
           "processing": true,
          "scrollX": false,
           "scrollY": false,
          "searching": true,
          "stateSave": false,
           "delay": 0,
          };

    var options = {
        "displayStart": 0,
        "lengthMenu": [10, 25, 50, 100],
        "orderClasses": true,
         "order": [[0,"asc"]],
         "orderMulti": true,
         "pageLength": 50,
         "pagingType": "full_numbers",
         "scrollCollapse": false,
         "searchDelay": 0,
         "stateDuration": 7200,
         "stripeClasses": [""],
          "responsive": true,};
    var ajax = {
            "serverSide": false,
"data": [{ /*data for the table*/
    };

    setTimeout(function() {
        var columns = {
            "columns": [
        {

         "contentPadding": "",
"defaultContent": "",
"name": "",
"orderable": false,
"searchable": false,
"title": "<input type='checkbox' name='multiselect_checkall' class='multiselect_checkall' />",
            "visible": true,
    "className": "row-select",
    "width": "",

    "data": null,
"render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
    var checkbox = "<input type='checkbox' name='multiselect_checkbox' value='" + first + "' class='multiselect_checkbox' />";
    var output = "";
    var startHtml = "";
    var endHtml = "";
    var attributes = "";



                        attributes += 'name="multiselect_checkbox check" ';
                attributes += 'class="multiselect_checkbox" ';

            var first;
    if (row.hasOwnProperty('id') && typeof('id') !== 'function') {
        first = row['id'];
    }

            if ("" != attributes) {
        var custom = "";

        custom += startHtml;
        custom += "<input type='checkbox' value='";
        custom += first;
        custom += "'";
        custom += attributes;
        custom += "/>"
        custom += endHtml;

        return custom;
    }

    output += startHtml;
    output += checkbox;
    output += endHtml;

    return output;
},
},
        {
        "contentPadding": "",
    "defaultContent": "",
    "name": "",
                "orderable": true,
                        "searchable": true,
            "title": "Name",
                        "visible": true,
        "className": "row-name",
            "width": "",

        "data": "name",
                },
        {
        "contentPadding": "",
    "defaultContent": "",
    "name": "",
                "orderable": true,
                        "searchable": true,
            "title": "Sex",
                        "visible": true,
        "className": "row-sex",
            "width": "",

        "data": "sex",
                },
        {
        "contentPadding": "",
    "defaultContent": "",
    "name": "",
                "orderable": true,
                        "searchable": true,
            "title": "Prio",
                        "visible": true,
        "className": "row-priority",
            "width": "",

        "data": "priority",
                },
        {
        "contentPadding": "",
    "defaultContent": "",
    "name": "",
                "orderable": true,
                        "searchable": true,
            "title": "Role",
                        "visible": true,
        "className": "",
            "width": "",

        "data": "role",
                },
        {
        "contentPadding": "",
    "defaultContent": "",
    "name": "",
                "orderable": true,
                        "searchable": true,
            "title": "(D)",
                        "visible": true,
        "className": "row-date",
            "width": "",

        "data": "bday",
                },
        {
        "contentPadding": "",
    "defaultContent": "",
    "name": "",
                "orderable": true,
                        "searchable": true,
            "title": "(M)",
                        "visible": true,
        "className": "row-month",
            "width": "",

        "data": "bmonth",
                },
        {
        "contentPadding": "",
    "defaultContent": "",
    "name": "",
                "orderable": true,
                        "searchable": true,
            "title": "(Y)",
                        "visible": true,
        "className": "row-year",
            "width": "",

        "data": "byear",
                },
        {
        "contentPadding": "",
    "defaultContent": "",
    "name": "",
                "orderable": true,
                        "searchable": true,
            "title": "Works",
                        "visible": true,
        "className": "",
            "width": "",

        "data": "works",
                },
        {
    "contentPadding": "",
"defaultContent": "",
"name": "",
"orderable": false,
"searchable": false,
"title": "Actions",
            "visible": true,
    "className": "row-buttons",
    "width": "",

    "data": "",
"render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
    var actionsString = "";


    var routeParameters, attributes, visibleFlag, roleFlag;

                routeParameters  = new Array();
        attributes = "";
        visibleFlag = true;
        roleFlag = true;


                        roleFlag = false;
                                roleFlag = true;

        if (true == visibleFlag && true == roleFlag) {
                                routeParameters["id"] = row.id;

            var route  = Routing.generate("artist_show", routeParameters);

                                attributes += 'rel="tooltip" ';
                                attributes += 'title="Show" ';
                                attributes += 'class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-icon icon-left" ';
                                attributes += 'role="button" ';

            var url  = "<a ";
            url += 'href="' + route + '" ';
            url += attributes;
                            url += ">";
            url += '<i class="entypo-info"></i> Show';
            url += "</a>";

            actionsString += url;
        }
                routeParameters  = new Array();
        attributes = "";
        visibleFlag = true;
        roleFlag = true;


                        roleFlag = false;
                                roleFlag = true;

        if (true == visibleFlag && true == roleFlag) {
                                routeParameters["id"] = row.id;

            var route  = Routing.generate("artist_edit", routeParameters);

                                attributes += 'rel="tooltip" ';
                                attributes += 'title="Edit" ';
                                attributes += 'class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-icon icon-left" ';
                                attributes += 'role="button" ';

            var url  = "<a ";
            url += 'href="' + route + '" ';
            url += attributes;
                                url += 'onclick="' + "return confirm('Are you sure?')" + '" ';
                            url += ">";
            url += '<i class="entypo-pencil"></i> Edit';
            url += "</a>";

            actionsString += url;
        }


    return actionsString;
 },
},
]
        };

        $.extend(defaults, features);
        $.extend(defaults, options);
        $.extend(defaults, ajax);
        $.extend(defaults, columns);

        if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( selector ) ) {
                        } else {
            var oTable = $(selector).DataTable(defaults);
        }




 var dt_wrapper = $("#artist_datatable" + "_wrapper");
dt_wrapper.find(".dataTables_scrollFootInner").append("\x0A");

dt_wrapper.find(".multiselect_checkall").click(function(event) {
var that = this;
dt_wrapper.find("input.multiselect_checkbox:checkbox").each(function() {
    this.checked = that.checked;
});
 });

dt_wrapper.find(".multiselect_action_click").on('click', function(event) {
var length = dt_wrapper.find("input.multiselect_checkbox:checkbox:checked").length;

event.preventDefault();

if (length > 0) {
    if (!confirm( "Are you sure?" )) {
        return;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("href"),
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            'data': $("input:checkbox:checked.multiselect_checkbox", oTable.rows().nodes()).serializeArray()
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            oTable.draw();
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest + ' ' + textStatus + ' ' +errorThrown);
        }
    })
} else {
    alert("You need to select at least one element.");
}
});

    }, features.delay);
});
```

CSS:

```
table.dataTable{table-layout: fixed !important}
.row-name[style]{width: 18% !important}
.row-select{width: 5% !important;}
.row-sex[style],.row-priority[style],.row-date[style],.row-month[style]    
{width: 5% !important;}
.row-year[style]{width: 6% !important;}
.row-buttons{width: 13%}
.row-owner, .row-spe{width:5% !important;}
.row-status{width: 5.5%;}
.row-sequence[style],.row-cat[style]{width:4% !important;}
.row-uid[style]{width: 12% !important;}
```

FYI: This is a `symfony` app and I am using SgDatatablebundle (https://github.com/stwe/DatatablesBundle ) to generate the datatable. Thanks in advance. Screenshort is attached with the sidebar open so that you can understand my problem. Look at the checkboxes (if you are almost blind like me and have trouble finding the misalignment! :p  )

[image]

Comment: have you tried setting `"autoWidth": true` in your DataTables features object?

Comment: setting `auto_width:true` resizes the width only after I hit F12 to open firebug.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it using this

```
$('.sidebar-toggle').click(function(){
    $('.dataTables_scrollHeadInner').css('width','100%');
    $('.table').css('width','100%');
    setTimeout(function(){
        datatable.columns.adjust().draw()}
    ,300);
});
```

set your timeout according to the time taken by sidebar to close and open